# No, draw it on white board."

Tags: sentence-construction

The board has two surface.

One is white board and another side is black board.

He was holding a chalk and wanted to draw on white board.

> "No, draw it on white board."
>
> "No, draw on white board."

Do we need to add a pronoun after verb?

He may draw anything or just scribble.

Comment: Not that this is constructive, but if the chalk is white, then drawing on the white board is futile.

Comment: Do you want to say a) he shouldn't draw on the whiteboard, or b) he should write on the blackboard?

Comment: *Board* is a countable noun, so it has to be *the* white board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The board has two surface**s**.
>
> One is **a** white board and **the other** side is **a** black board.
>
> He was holding a chalk and wanted to draw on **the** white board.
>
> "No, draw it on **the** white board."
>
> "No, draw on **the** white board."
>
> Do we need to add a pronoun after **the** verb?

The answer is, no you don't. "Draw" is a verb which may take an object but doesn't have to.

Comment: How would he write on the whiteboard with some chalk?

Comment: @Araucaria chalk need not be white.

Comment: @VarunKN Quite so, but you can't write on shiny plastic with chalk.

Comment: Well, in rural parts of my country, they use portions of white painted walls as boards and use colored chalks, to teach primary classes. So technically there are non-glossy 'white' boards too. But, if it's glossy, chalk is useless. I agree.